# What happens when you find the derivative of $f(x) =|x^2-1|$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) =|x^2-1|$.

I'm trying to see if this function has a point of inflection and even though looking at the graph tells me the answer already, I was just curious.

What happens to the modulus part when you differentiate it? Would you just take the piecewise version of the function and differentiate each function?

Comment: You can split the domain into positive and negative, then know what to do with the absolute value sign.  That leaves you with $0$, where the corner should give you the impression it is not differentiable.  You can prove that because any neighborhood of $0$ has part with slope $1$ and part with slope $-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the absolute value as $\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}$, which we can differentiate with the chain rule.

Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}\right]&=\frac12\left((x^2-1)^2\right)^{-\frac12}\cdot 2(x^2-1)\cdot 2x\\
&=\frac{x^2-1}{\left((x^2-1)^2\right)^\frac12}\cdot 2x\\
&= \frac{x^2-1}{|x^2-1|}\cdot 2x\\
&=\operatorname{sgn}(x^2-1)\cdot 2x
\end{align}
$$
We used the absolute value and sign functions with the following definitions
$$|f(x)|=\sqrt{f^2(x)}$$
$$\operatorname{sgn}(f(x))= \begin{cases} 
      0 & f(x)=0 \\
      \frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)} & f(x)\neq 0
   \end{cases}
$$
(Note the absolute value can be in the numerator or denominator, the sign function works either way)

You can find the derivative of the general case (as stated by Klein bottle) by applying chain rule to the square root definition of the absolute value function. Give it a try tbh

Comment: that's interesting I've never encountered sgn(x) since this is my first semester at university for maths. I will give it a try thanks for the help

Comment: minor typo in the definition of the sign function: the condition should be over $f(x)$, not over $x$

Comment: @Didier fixed it

Comment: There must be something wrong here, because the above calculation asserts that $f^\prime(1) = 0$, but $f^\prime(1)$ does not exist.

Comment: @JasonZimba the derivative of the sign function can exist at 0 under a generalized notion of the derivative using the Dirac delta function. You can find more info and formal definitions on wolfram math world and wikipedia

Comment: @CaptainChicky Thank you. I have a Ph.D. in mathematical physics (admittedly from a long time ago!), so delta functions are quite familiar to me. But I’m doubtful that we should be appealing to generalized notions of the derivative for OP’s question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \vert f(x)\vert = f'(x) \text{sgn}(f(x))$$

Where $\text{sgn}(\cdot)$ is the signum function.

$$\text{sgn}(f(x)) = \dfrac{\vert f(x) \vert}{f(x)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go